# GCC 7.4.0 compilation gets stuck at contribs/download_prerequisites

Tags: gcc, ftp, wget, compiler

When running `contribs/download_prerequisites` the script gets stuck without any output. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by turning off `no-verbose` for wget in the script that the download was getting stuck at "logging in as anonymous" from FTP:

```
--2023-10-16 23:06:18--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-6.1.0.tar.bz2
           => ‘./gmp-6.1.0.tar.bz2’
Resolving gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)... 8.43.85.97, 2620:52:3:1:0:246e:9693:128c
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)|8.43.85.97|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ...
```

The fix was to replace the `ftp://` with `http://`  in the script's `base_url`.